# SVG sprite icons using CSS background positioning and sizing

Tags: css, svg

I am developing a website for a client that uses a SVG sprite. The SVG file contains icons of similar size. The sprite is being displayed using CSS background properties. Some of the icons are part of links and others are for text inputs and lists. You can see how they are used here: [working example](http://staging.flagstaff.ab.ca/). The issue is affecting positioning and sizing for some of the icons. You can see this in the top search input and the footer navigation in the bottom left. I cannot seem to get the positioning and sizing correct for these icons. I have got it correct for the Facebook and Twitter icons, but similar code is not working for the other sprite icons. I have attached the CSS and SVG code below for reference. I have also attached the sprite in PNG format for visual reference. Any suggestions? Thanks.

CSS:

```
.footernav a.has-icon:before {
    content:'';
    display:inline-block;
    width:2.090em;
    height:1.47em;
    margin-right:14px;
    background:url(../images/sprite.svg) no-repeat 0 0;
    background-size:1.407em 8.045em;
    font-size:1.333em
}

.footernav a.sm:before {
    margin-right:0
}

.footernav .has-icon.icon-contactus:before {
    background-position:0 -2.210em
}

.footernav .has-icon.icon-webmap:before {
    background-position:0 -26.679em
}

.footernav .has-icon.icon-sitemap:before {
    background-position:0 -28.751em
}

.footernav .sm:link {
    display:block;
    width:1.34em;
    height:1.36em;
    background:url(../images/sprite.svg) no-repeat 0 0;
    background-size:1.407em 8.045em;
    text-indent:-999em;
    font-size:1.566em
}

.footernav .icon-facebook:link {
    background-position:0 0
}

.footernav .icon-twitter:link {
    background-position:0 -1.474em
}
```

SVG (exported from Illustrator):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 20.1.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
 viewBox="0 0 21.1 120.7" style="enable-background:new 0 0 21.1 120.7;" preserveAspectRatio="none" xml:space="preserve">
<g>
<rect x="0.6" y="0.1" style="fill:#517CBE;" width="20" height="20"/>
<path style="fill:#FFFFFF;" d="M8.6,8.8h0.8V8c0-0.3,0-0.9,0.3-1.2C10,6.4,10.4,6.2,11,6.2c1,0,1.5,0.1,1.5,0.1l-0.2,1.2
    c0,0-0.3-0.1-0.7-0.1c-0.3,0-0.6,0.1-0.6,0.4v0.9h1.3l-0.1,1.2H11V14H9.5V9.9H8.6V8.8z"/>
</g>
<g style="enable-background:new    ;">
<g>
    <rect x="0.6" y="22.1" style="fill:#575858;" width="20" height="20"/>
    <path style="fill:#575858;" d="M14.5,29.7c-0.3,0.1-0.6,0.2-0.9,0.3c0.3-0.2,0.6-0.5,0.7-0.9c-0.3,0.2-0.7,0.3-1,0.4
        c-0.3-0.3-0.7-0.5-1.2-0.5c-0.9,0-1.6,0.7-1.6,1.6c0,0.1,0,0.3,0,0.4c-1.3-0.1-2.5-0.7-3.3-1.7C7,29.4,6.9,29.7,6.9,30
        c0,0.6,0.3,1.1,0.7,1.3c-0.3,0-0.5-0.1-0.7-0.2v0c0,0.8,0.6,1.4,1.3,1.6c-0.1,0-0.3,0.1-0.4,0.1c-0.1,0-0.2,0-0.3,0
        c0.2,0.6,0.8,1.1,1.5,1.1c-0.6,0.4-1.3,0.7-2,0.7c-0.1,0-0.3,0-0.4,0c0.7,0.5,1.6,0.7,2.5,0.7c3,0,4.6-2.5,4.6-4.6
        c0-0.1,0-0.1,0-0.2C14,30.3,14.3,30,14.5,29.7"/>
</g>
<g>
    <rect x="0.6" y="22.1" style="fill:#429CD6;" width="20" height="20"/>
    <path style="fill:#FFFFFF;" d="M14.5,29.7c-0.3,0.1-0.6,0.2-0.9,0.3c0.3-0.2,0.6-0.5,0.7-0.9c-0.3,0.2-0.7,0.3-1,0.4
        c-0.3-0.3-0.7-0.5-1.2-0.5c-0.9,0-1.6,0.7-1.6,1.6c0,0.1,0,0.3,0,0.4c-1.3-0.1-2.5-0.7-3.3-1.7C7,29.4,6.9,29.7,6.9,30
        c0,0.6,0.3,1.1,0.7,1.3c-0.3,0-0.5-0.1-0.7-0.2v0c0,0.8,0.6,1.4,1.3,1.6c-0.1,0-0.3,0.1-0.4,0.1c-0.1,0-0.2,0-0.3,0
        c0.2,0.6,0.8,1.1,1.5,1.1c-0.6,0.4-1.3,0.7-2,0.7c-0.1,0-0.3,0-0.4,0c0.7,0.5,1.6,0.7,2.5,0.7c3,0,4.6-2.5,4.6-4.6
        c0-0.1,0-0.1,0-0.2C14,30.3,14.3,30,14.5,29.7"/>
</g>
</g>
<rect x="-524" y="-189.9" style="fill:#429CD6;" width="400" height="400"/>
<g>
<path style="fill:#575757;" d="M14.9,49.4c0-2.8-3.4-5.2-7.4-5.2s-7.4,2.4-7.4,5.2c0,1.5,0.9,3,2.4,3.9c-0.2,0.5-0.8,1.4-1.3,1.9
    c0,0,0,0,0,0c-0.1,0.1-0.2,0.3-0.2,0.5c0,0.4,0.3,0.7,0.7,0.7c0,0,3.1-0.4,4.7-1.8c0.4,0,0.7,0.1,1.1,0.1
    C11.5,54.6,14.9,52.2,14.9,49.4z"/>
<path style="fill:#575757;" d="M18.7,55.9C20.1,55,21,53.4,21,52c0-2.2-2.1-4.2-5.1-5c-0.2-0.1-0.5,0.1-0.5,0.3s0.1,0.5,0.3,0.5
    c2.6,0.6,4.4,2.4,4.4,4.1c0,1.2-0.9,2.6-2.2,3.3c-0.1,0.1-0.2,0.2-0.2,0.4c0,0.7,0.7,1.7,1.3,2.3c-0.9-0.2-2.9-0.7-3.9-1.6
    c-0.1-0.1-0.2-0.1-0.4-0.1c-0.4,0-0.8,0.1-1.2,0.1c-1.5,0-2.8-0.3-4-1c-0.2-0.1-0.5,0-0.6,0.2c-0.1,0.2,0,0.5,0.2,0.6
    c1.3,0.7,2.9,1.1,4.5,1.1c0.3,0,0.7,0,1.1-0.1c1.6,1.4,4.7,1.8,4.7,1.8c0.4,0,0.7-0.3,0.7-0.7c0-0.2-0.1-0.4-0.2-0.5
    C19.5,57.3,18.9,56.4,18.7,55.9z"/>
</g>
<g>
<path style="fill:#575757;" d="M14.6,66.7c-1,0-1.8-0.8-1.8-1.8c0-1,0.8-1.8,1.8-1.8c1,0,1.8,0.8,1.8,1.8
    C16.4,65.9,15.6,66.7,14.6,66.7 M14.6,71.5c0,0,3.8-4.7,3.8-6.8c0-2.1-1.7-3.8-3.8-3.8c-2.1,0-3.8,1.7-3.8,3.8
    C10.8,66.8,14.6,71.5,14.6,71.5 M5.8,80.6l-3.9-1.6V67.7l3.9,1.6V80.6z M20.5,80.3V66.2l-1.4-0.8c-0.1,0.4-0.3,0.8-0.5,1.3l0.5,0.4
    v11.2l-3.9-1.6v-5.1C15.1,71.8,15,71.9,15,72l-0.4,0.5L14.2,72c0-0.1-0.1-0.2-0.3-0.3v5.6L7.2,80V68.8l3.5-1.2
    c-0.2-0.4-0.4-0.9-0.6-1.2l-4.3,1.5l-5.3-2.2v14.2L5.8,82l9.4-3.9v0L20.5,80.3z"/>
</g>
<g>
<path style="fill:#575757;" d="M20.5,96.5v3.6c0,0.3-0.1,0.6-0.3,0.8c-0.2,0.2-0.5,0.3-0.8,0.3h-3.6c-0.3,0-0.6-0.1-0.8-0.3
    c-0.2-0.2-0.3-0.5-0.3-0.8v-3.6c0-0.3,0.1-0.6,0.3-0.8c0.2-0.2,0.5-0.3,0.8-0.3H17v-2.1h-5.7v2.1h1.1c0.3,0,0.6,0.1,0.8,0.3
    c0.2,0.2,0.3,0.5,0.3,0.8v3.6c0,0.3-0.1,0.6-0.3,0.8c-0.2,0.2-0.5,0.3-0.8,0.3H8.8c-0.3,0-0.6-0.1-0.8-0.3
    c-0.2-0.2-0.3-0.5-0.3-0.8v-3.6c0-0.3,0.1-0.6,0.3-0.8s0.5-0.3,0.8-0.3h1.1v-2.1H4.1v2.1h1.1c0.3,0,0.6,0.1,0.8,0.3
    s0.3,0.5,0.3,0.8v3.6c0,0.3-0.1,0.6-0.3,0.8c-0.2,0.2-0.5,0.3-0.8,0.3H1.6c-0.3,0-0.6-0.1-0.8-0.3c-0.2-0.2-0.3-0.5-0.3-0.8v-3.6
    c0-0.3,0.1-0.6,0.3-0.8s0.5-0.3,0.8-0.3h1.1v-2.1c0-0.4,0.1-0.7,0.4-1s0.6-0.4,1-0.4h5.7v-2.1H8.8c-0.3,0-0.6-0.1-0.8-0.3
    c-0.2-0.2-0.3-0.5-0.3-0.8v-3.6c0-0.3,0.1-0.6,0.3-0.8C8.2,84.1,8.5,84,8.8,84h3.6c0.3,0,0.6,0.1,0.8,0.3c0.2,0.2,0.3,0.5,0.3,0.8
    v3.6c0,0.3-0.1,0.6-0.3,0.8c-0.2,0.2-0.5,0.3-0.8,0.3h-1.1v2.1H17c0.4,0,0.7,0.1,1,0.4c0.3,0.3,0.4,0.6,0.4,1v2.1h1.1
    c0.3,0,0.6,0.1,0.8,0.3S20.5,96.2,20.5,96.5L20.5,96.5z"/>
</g>
<path id="path-2" style="opacity:0.54;fill:#575757;enable-background:new    ;" d="M14.3,114.2h-0.8l-0.3-0.3
c1-1.2,1.6-2.7,1.6-4.2c0-3.6-2.9-6.5-6.5-6.5h0c-3.6,0-6.5,2.9-6.5,6.5s2.9,6.5,6.5,6.5c1.6,0,3-0.6,4.2-1.6l0.3,0.3v0.8l5,5
l1.5-1.5L14.3,114.2L14.3,114.2z M8.3,114.2c-2.5,0-4.5-2-4.5-4.5c0-2.5,2-4.5,4.5-4.5h0c2.5,0,4.5,2,4.5,4.5
C12.8,112.2,10.8,114.2,8.3,114.2z"/>
<rect style="display:none;opacity:0.5;fill:#424243;" width="100" height="22.1"/>
</svg>
```

[image: PNG sprite example]

Answer (score 0):

It will help to remove `preserveAspectRatio="none"` from your SVG and fix the dimensions, e.g. `width="100" height="600"`.

With those dimensions in mind, set the `background-size` accordingly in your CSS. Always use `1em` for `width` and `height`, and use `font-size` to control the scaling of the icon element.

```
.has-icon {
    background-image: url(...);
    background-size: 1em 6em;
    width: 1em;
    height: 1em;
    font-size: 1em; /* Just tweak this property */
}
```

To access each icon, use multiples of `1em` in `background-position`.

```
.has-icon.icon-twitter {
    background-position: 0 -1em;
}
```

This assumes that each icon fits in a square area and there are no gaps between squares; if your SVG doesn't adhere to this, it may be a good idea to make it so. Good luck!

Comment: Where are you recommending the dimensions be changed to `width="100" height="600"` in the SVG file? Thanks.

Comment: Simply add them to the `<svg>` element.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`.module.search .icon-search {
    display: block;
    width: 2.692em;
    height: 2.692em;
    position: absolute;
    top: 4px;
    left: 4px;
    background: transparent url(../images/sprite.svg) no-repeat 0 -6.556em;
    background-size: 1.407em 7.8em;
    font-size: 1em;
}`

I modified the `background-size` and the `top: 4px;`

Comment: Thanks. The code adjustments worked. Could you elaborate on why you changed the second background-size value to '7.8em' from '8.045em'?

Comment: Yeah so, that is the height location on the sprite according to what you have as your size (or em for the page)